# Length of a list with multiple entries is 1?

Tags: r

From the following code we can see there is a 2D array of `list`'s:

```
> coldists[3,4]
[[1]]
     mean        sd 
0.5752512 0.4067640 
> class(coldists[3,4][1])
[1] "list"
> class(coldists[3,4][[1]])
[1] "numeric"
```

My confusion is: why is the length of the list reported as `[1]` instead of `[2]` ?

```
length(coldists[3,4])
[1] 1
```

After all there appear to be 2 entries (`mean` and `sd`) in that list ..

Comment: use lengths instead of length

Comment: thx for that tip sathish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a list containing a vector with two elements.

```
x <- list(c(mean = 0.5752512, sd = 0.4067640))
x
#> [[1]]
#>      mean        sd 
#> 0.5752512 0.4067640
```

Because it only contains one vector, it has length one.

```
length(x)
#> [1] 1
```

However, when we get the length of the vector, it has length 2.

```
length(x[[1]])
#> [1] 2
```

When we use single brackets, it gets a sublist rather than extracting the vector. This sublist is still a length one list containing a vector with two elements.

```
length(x[1])
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: I have been unable to come up with how to access the second element of that vector. Any help there?

Comment: coldists[3,4][[1]][2]

Answer (score 2):

Here, `coldists[3,4]` is a list with one element. Inside this unique list element there is a vector of length 2 (mean, sd).
If you want to have the length of the vector inside the list, you need to specify it like :
`length(coldists[3,4][[1]])`